# how do i return a spliced array using multiple indexes from a different array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, splice

```
dft=["t", "h", "i", "s", "I", "s", "S", "p", "i", "n", "a", "l", "T", "a", "p"];
ans=[4, 6, 12, -1];  
for(x=0;x<ans-1;x++){
dft.splice(ans[x],0,"-");}
return dft;
```

I am trying to return an array that has "-" placed into the dft array using the indexes in the ans array except the -1 index.

result im getting is ["t", "h", "i", "s", "I", "s", "S", "p", "i", "n", "a", "l", "T", "a", "p"]

[this is the codepen i am working on](http://codepen.io/nunez7890/pen/EZzBBV?editors=0012)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it's not doing anything because your for loop end condition should be checking the loop parameter `x` against the *length* of the `ans` array, i.e. `x < ans.length -1`. Secondly, since `splice` is changing the array, your `ans` indices will be incorrect after you insert the first hyphen, so you should do it in reverse order like so:

```js
dft = ["t", "h", "i", "s", "I", "s", "S", "p", "i", "n", "a", "l", "T", "a", "p"];
ans = [4, 6, 12, -1];

for (x = ans.length - 2; x >= 0; x--) {
    dft.splice(ans[x], 0, "-");
}

console.log(dft);
```

We start at the end of the array, which would be `ans.length - 1`, except you want to skip the last element, so we start at `ans.length - 2`. Remember though that **this assumes that the last element should be ignored**.

Answer (score 0):

You can reach your desired result with `Array#reduce`.

```js
let dft = ["t", "h", "i", "s", "I", "s", "S", "p", "i", "n", "a", "l", "T", "a", "p"];
let ans = [4, 6, 12, -1];
let res = dft.reduce((s,a,i) => {
  (ans.indexOf(i) > -1) ? s.push(a, '-') : s.push(a);
  return s;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort the index array and do in the reverse order otherwise it would change the index of other elements.

```js
var dft = ["t", "h", "i", "s", "I", "s", "S", "p", "i", "n", "a", "l", "T", "a", "p"],
  ans = [4, 6, 12, -1];

// sor the array to place - at the last higher index first
ans.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
});
// get array length
var x = ans.length;
// iterate upto index reach to 0 or reaching to -1
while (x-- && ans[x] > -1) {
  dft.splice(ans[x], 0, "-");
}

console.log(dft);
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays do not have a numeric primitive, so you want your for loop condition to read x < ans.length.

Your index also needs to be ans[x] + x, because each splice() is increasing the length of the array by 1.

These changes alone should accomplish your stated goal.  However I would also add:

- you should be declaring variables purposefully, rather than using implicit globals.
- you can replace your for loop using the forEach() method, which can make your intention more clear.
- you probably want spacing around terms and operators, which also helps readability.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, a solution with [`Array#reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight)

```js
var array = ["t", "h", "i", "s", "I", "s", "S", "p", "i", "n", "a", "l", "T", "a", "p"],
    indices = [4, 6, 12, -1],
    result = indices.reduceRight((r, i) => (~i && r.splice(i, 0, '-'), r), array);

console.log(result.join(''));
```